# Returning a collection list using a filter from an array of id in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

So I already got this working using a loop but is wondering is there is a cleaner way to do this.

Basically i got a model that got an array of ids from another model,  currently I loop every id and add manually model to a new collection using this filter on the model collection.

```
getOneById : function(id){
    return this.filter(function(data) {
        return data.get("id") == id;
    });
},
```

Is there a way to directly return a list doing something like

```
getAllById : function(arrayIds){
    return _(this.filter(function(data) {
        ??????? return data.get("id") == eachID;
    }));
},
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could reduce the looping by checking to see if the id of your object is at an index > -1 in the array:

```
function(arrayIds){
  var models = _.select(collection, function(model){
    return (_.indexOf(arrayIds, model.id) > -1);
  });
  return models;
}
```

this requires the inclusion of underscore.js in your code, but since you're already using backbone, you already have that.

Comment: i think it should read `collection.models` instead of `collection`

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Having **collection** (Backbone.Collection) and **arrayIds**

```
var collection2 = new Backbone.Collection();
collection2.add(collection.models.filter(function(model){
    return arrayIds.indexOf(model.id) !== -1;
}));
```

Four lines :D

```
console.assert(collection2.length === arrayIds.length)  //OK
```